# Codeigniter Muliple File with Different ext

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I Am Uploading Screenshot And File In Codeigniter Using `CI_UPLOAD` Library. Now  Screenshot uploading well, after that when I am uploading file it showing error. I search a lot in google to fix this issue but didn't get solution. When i am doing `$config['allowed_types']=TRUE` in file its working but I want only **mp3 / 3gp / mp4 / avi / sis / sisx / jar** files

```
$field1 = 'ss';
$config['upload_path'] = IMAGE_UPLOAD_PATH;
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pjpeg';
$ext = $this->get_ext($_FILES[$field1]['name']);
$config['file_name'] = date("U")."-screenshot.$ext";;
$this->upload->initialize($config);
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($field1)) {
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
} else {
    $img_data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $data['ss'] = DOMAIN.IMAGE_UPLOAD_PATH.'/'.$img_data['upload_data']['file_name'];
}
///iits working file
//// below code not working
$field2 = 'file';
$config1['upload_path'] = FILE_UPLOAD_PATH;
// i try it with 'mp3|jar' etc
$config1['allowed_types'] = $_FILES[$field2]['type']; 
$ext = $this->get_ext($_FILES[$field2]['name']);
$config1['file_name'] = date("U")."-".$title.".".$ext."";
$config1['max_size'] = 400000;
$this->upload->initialize($config1);
if (!$this->upload->do_upload($field2)) {
    $error = array_merge(array(@$error),array('error' => @$this->upload->display_errors()));
} else {
    $file_data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $data['size'] = $file_data['upload_data']['file_size'];
    $data['file_link'] = DOMAIN.FILE_UPLOAD_PATH.'/'.$file_data['upload_data']['file_name'];
}
```

showing error:

```
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed
```

Now I Am Tired to searching and fixing this problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including/searching config/mimes.php

```
'jar' => 'application/java-archive'
```

Comment: Can I All Mime Type Of
nth|thn|jad|sis|sisx|zip|3gp|mp4|avi
any way thx its working

Comment: Add as many as you wish if you can find the proper mime headers.